# How do you apply Monte Carlo simulations to regressions?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, montecarlo

I am working on a data analysis project that requires me to use Monte Carlo simulations of a standard linear regression. For the purposes of this project, the variables we are looking to vary are the effect size and the sample size of the simulated data. I am however new at running Monte Carlo simulations, and could use some help troubleshooting my code.

So in order to understand the problem, I first made use of the Vignette that comes with the MonteCarlo package just to understand how the package works. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MonteCarlo/vignettes/MonteCarlo-Vignette.html

As I understand it, the Monte Carlo package runs a function you define a number of times you specify, then returns user defined outputs. I tried to generate a function that created the elements the MonteCarlo() function requires: a means of generating data, a statistical method, a decision, and an outcome. The model gets to 23% complete, than crashes. The code I have cobbled together from different sources on the web is presented below.

```
####Creating a function to run regressions in a Monte Carlo simulation.
###Generating function to pull p-values out of regression models:
lmp <- function (modelobject) {
  if (class(modelobject) != "lm") stop("Not an object of class 'lm' ")
  f <- summary(modelobject)$fstatistic
  p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
  attributes(p) <- NULL
  return(p)
}

###Creating function for regression analysis to be passed to the MonteCarlo() function.
Regression<-function(n, corr){
# create the initial x variable
x1 <- rnorm(n, 15, 5)

# x2, x3, and x4 in a matrix, these will be modified to meet the criteria
x2 <- scale(matrix( rnorm(n), ncol=1 ))

# put all into 1 matrix for simplicity
x12 <- cbind(scale(x1),x2)

# find the current correlation matrix
c1 <- var(x12)

# cholesky decomposition to get independence
chol1 <- solve(chol(c1))

newx <-  x12 %*% chol1 

# create new correlation structure (zeros can be replaced with other r vals)
newc <- matrix( 
  c(1  , corr,  
    corr, 1), ncol=2 )

# check that it is positive definite
chol2 <- chol(newc)

sample <- newx %*% chol2 * sd(x1) + mean(x1)

###Defining test statistic to be calculated on each sample.
stat<-lm(sample[,1]~sample[,2])

# get test decision:
decision<-abs(lmp(stat))<.05

# return result:
return(list("decision"=decision))
}

#define parameter grid for monte carlo simulation:

n_grid<-c(50,100,250,500)
corr_grid<-seq(0,.9,0.05)


# collect parameter grids in list:
param_list=list("n"=n_grid, "corr"=corr_grid)

####Running A Monte Carlo Simulation
library(MonteCarlo)
MC_result<-MonteCarlo(func=Regression, nrep=1000, param_list=param_list)
summary(MC_result)
```

What I was hoping to get was a MonteCarlo object that I could make into a table like the one in the Monte Carlo vignette, something like this:

```
## \begin{table}[h]
## \centering
## \resizebox{ 1 \textwidth}{!}{%
## \begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr }
## \hline\hline\\\\
##  scale && \multicolumn{ 6 }{c}{ 1 } &  & \multicolumn{ 6 }{c}{ 2 } \\ 
## n/loc &  & 0 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 1 &  & 0 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 1 \\ 
##  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
## 50 &  & 0.06 & 0.28 & 0.81 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 &  & 0.05 & 0.12 & 0.28 & 0.56 & 0.80 & 0.94 \\ 
## 100 &  & 0.04 & 0.49 & 0.97 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 &  & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.53 & 0.83 & 0.98 & 1.00 \\ 
## 250 &  & 0.05 & 0.88 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 &  & 0.05 & 0.36 & 0.89 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
## 500 &  & 0.05 & 0.99 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 &  & 0.05 & 0.59 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ 
## \\
## \\
## \hline\hline
## \end{tabular}%
## }
## \caption{ decision  }
## \end{table}
```

Instead, I got the following table:

```
 > ###Creating a LateX Table
> MakeTable(output=MC_result, rows="n", cols="corr", digits=3, include_meta=FALSE)
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{ 1 \textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr }
\hline\hline\\\\
n/corr &  & 0 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.15 & 0.2 & 0.25 & 0.3 & 0.35 & 0.4 & 0.45 & 0.5 & 0.55 & 0.6 & 0.65 & 0.7 & 0.75 & 0.8 & 0.85 & 0.9 \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
50 &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 \\ 
100 &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 \\ 
250 &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 \\ 
500 &  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 & 1.000 \\ 
\\
\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{ decision  }
\end{table}
```

The problem with this table, is it is completely unbelievable for the subject matter. It makes no sense that a linear regression would generate only 100% significant p-values or 0% significant p-values. There should be a region of the table where some combinations of correlation and sample size result in some p-values being significant and some p-values being insignificant. That is to say, some of the proportions should be between 0 and 1, rather than equal to 0 and 1.

Thoughts on what I am doing wrong with this function to result in this outcome would be appreciated.

Comment: you never defined the object `corr` in `Regression()`, maybe its something else in your environment and making the decomposition of `newc` impossible.

Comment: I have tried cleaning the environment of all objects using the rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE)) function, there was no change in the outcome.

In terms of defining corr, I thought I had defined corr by putting it in the original correlation matrix:

# create new correlation structure (zeros can be replaced with other r vals)
newc <- matrix( 
  c(1  , corr,  
    corr, 1), ncol=2 )

and then passing the values I wanted in the corr grid:
corr_grid<-seq(0,1,0.1)

Is there an additional step I need to perform to define corr in the Regression() function?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, i missed that. well, the error message you are receiving is telling you one thing: the matrix passed to `chol` is not positive definite. a.k.a. it can't be factored. This could be the case if corr ended up being 1, such as would be the case if you accidentally correlated the same variable with itself? I don't know what you are passing to the argument `corr`. Though I have to be honest, you're just asking for trouble by trying to reinvent the wheel. If you want to do a permutation test, just replicate the an `lm` model 1000 times, using a resampling paradigm. try `?Boot`

Comment: OH, duh. Due to the way the sequence was setup, corr_grid contains the value 1. Consequently, when the function tries to resolve for that value, the grid becomes 1,1,1,1, which is impossible to factor.

Perfect. Now all I need to understand is why the resultant table looks buggy. Updating the base response with the new results.

Comment: correct, the result of `matrix(c(1,1,1,1), ncol = 2)` is not invertible